# How to solve this error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a query that works on SQLAnywhere, but for some reason does not work on SSMS, tell me what is wrong with it, because I get an error: **Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.**

```
 SELECT (CASE 
                WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from READCHK_READSEQ_OVRCOMP where  READCHK_ID = :readChkId AND READSEQ_ID = :readSeqId) THEN 'M'
                WHEN ( COUNT(*) =  Coalesce(SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM READCHKFLEX flx WHERE flx.READCHKFLD_ID = rcfld.READCHKFLD_ID AND flx.READCHK_ID =  :readChkId) ), 0 )) THEN 'A' 
           ELSE 'I' END) CompletionStatus
     FROM READSEQFLD rsfld
     JOIN READSEQ rseq on rseq.READSEQ_ID = rsfld.READSEQ_ID
     JOIN READCHKPAGEFLD rcpf on rcpf.READCHKTYPE_ID = rseq.READCHKTYPE_ID and rcpf.READCHKFLD_ID = rsfld.READCHKFLD_ID
     JOIN READCHKFLD  rcfld on rcfld.READCHKFLD_ID = rcpf.READCHKFLD_ID
    WHERE rsfld.READSEQ_ID = :readSeqId
      AND Upper(rsfld.ACTIVATE_FLG) = 'Y'
      AND rcfld.CALFORM_ID IS NULL
      AND (rcpf.fld_properties is null or Upper(rcpf.fld_properties) <> 'HIDE');
```

How to fix that?

Comment: The error tells you whats wrong. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to get the status based on this request

Comment: You'll need to rewrite the query. SQL Server doesn't allow aggregate functions on expressions "containing an aggregate or a subquery" - you are attempting to aggregate an expression containing **both** prohibited items. `SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) ...`

Comment: You would likely be better off giving us sample data, expected results and an explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As it's parameterized it's a constant value. I doubt you actually wanted a sum of the same value. Multiplication would work if so.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't allow aggregates on expressions containing sub queries.

I *think* the following should preserve your original behaviour

1. Append a CTE definition before the existing `SELECT`

```
WITH flx_agg
     AS (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt,
                READCHKFLD_ID
         FROM   READCHKFLEX flx
         WHERE  flx.READCHK_ID = :readChkId
         GROUP  BY READCHKFLD_ID)
SELECT ...
```

2. Add an outer join to that to your existing join conditions

```
LEFT JOIN flx_agg
       ON flx_agg.READCHKFLD_ID = rcfld.READCHKFLD_ID
```

3. Change the offending `CASE WHEN` condition to

```
WHEN COUNT(*) = COALESCE(SUM(flx_agg.Cnt), 0)
```